# Solve $(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dx-xdy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dx-xdy=0$

I suspect this is homogoneus equation after we divide sides by $y$. But I don't know how to contiunue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write thise equation in the form $$(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dx-xdy=0$$
Rearranging gives: $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}=\frac yx+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac yx\right)^2}$$
Try substituting $u=y/x$. Then $y'=u+xu'$, giving: $$\require{cancel} \cancel{u}+xu'=\cancel{u}+\sqrt{1+u^2}.$$
To solve this, you get $$\frac{u'}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}=\frac 1x\implies \sinh^{-1} u=c+\log x\implies u=\sinh(c+\log x)$$So the final solution is$$y=x\sinh(c+\log x)$$

Answer (score 0):

note that we can write $$1+\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2+1}-\frac{x}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ for $$y>0$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/800462)

Comment: ok i don't understand what you meant, the same idea can you read above